# How do I get back my plain old setInterval() from being zoned?

Tags: angular

i.e. is there a way to execute `setInterval()` in Angular2 without triggering its change-detection routine everytime?

Answer (score 0):

**setInterval()** can be used with Angular2 without  triggering changedetection as follow,

(Don't understand your purpose. its better if you could tell us what do you want to do?)

```
setInterval(function(){        //<-----rather than using setInterval(()=>{...});
  console.log("No Chnagedetection");
},1000);
```